# Find if a given number is a sum of a given set (with repetitons allowed) using recursion (java)

Tags: java, recursion, sum, subset, stack-overflow

Im trying to find if a  given number is a sum of a given set,
for example: the number `12` is a sum of the set `s{3,2}`,
because:

```
3+3+3+3=12
or
2+2+2+2+2+2=12
```

but `14` is not a sum of `s{8,10}` because you can't create the number `14` with `sums of s`.
I'm trying to write the code in java using only recursion, and without loops.
here is the code:

```
   public static boolean isSumOf(int[]s,int n)
   {
     return isSumOf(s,n,0,0,0);
   }


   private static boolean isSumOf(int[]s,int n,int i,int sum,int m)
   {
       boolean with=false;
       boolean without=false;

       if(i==s.length)
        return false;

       if(sum==n)   
        return true;

       if(m<=n)
        {
            with=isSumOf(s,n,i,sum+s[i]*m,m++);
            without=isSumOf(s,n,i,sum,m++);            
        }
       else
        {
            i=i++;
            m=0;
            isSumOf(s,n,i,sum,m);
        }

       return (with||without); 

   }
```

The code is compiled ok, but I get a stackOverFlowError when i run a test on it.
here is the code for the test:

```
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {  
      int[]a={18,10,6};
      int x=18+10+6;
      System.out.println(Ex14.isSumOf(a,x));
  }
```

please help!!!

Comment: Just Curious.. Why downvotes on this question? I think it is clearly specified what OP wants. And also has the code that he tried?

Comment: A stack overflow suggests your code is not terminating. Have you stepped through using a debugger, with a simple example, to see why your `return` statements are not executing?

Comment: I would suggest you rename the variables in your methods. It's hard to determine what `n`, `i` and `m` refer to. It may help you spot your error too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this looks bad:

```
with=isSumOf(s,n,i,sum+s[i]*m,m++);
without=isSumOf(s,n,i,sum,m++);
```

use

```
with=isSumOf(s,n,i,sum+s[i]*m,++m);
without=isSumOf(s,n,i,sum,++m);
```

if you want to have `m` one higher in the called method.

Other than that, I have no clue what the code does due to poor variable naming.

Also this line:

```
i=i++;
```

has no effect, replace it with one of the following if you want to increment `i`:

```
i++;
i += 1;
i = i + 1;
i = ++i;
```

And if you don't use the result of the call

```
isSumOf(s,n,i,sum,m);
```

there is no point in calling it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work - and I don't see any indication that you don't want a ready-made answer (which I am sure you would state if this was homework) so here goes:

```
public class IsSumOf {
  // set - The numbers allowed.
  // total - The number I want to achieve.
  // i - Where we are in the set.
  // sum - List of numbers used so far.
  // n - The number we just subtracted (or 0 if none).
  // Note that sum and n are only used for the printing of the route.
  private static boolean isSumOf(int[] set, int total, int i, LinkedList<Integer> sum, int n) {
    // Found the set if we are now at 0.
    boolean is = (total == 0);
    // Look no further if no more to try.
    if ( total > 0 ) {
      // Look no further if we've exhausted the array.
      if ( i < set.length ) {
        // Try or consume this number in the set (or not) and try again.
        is = isSumOf(set, total - set[i], i, sum, set[i] ) 
                || isSumOf(set, total - set[i], i+1, sum, set[i] ) 
                || isSumOf(set, total, i+1, sum, 0 ) ;
      }
    }
    // Keep track of the route.
    if ( is && sum != null && n != 0) {
      // Add backwards so we get the order right when printed.
      sum.addFirst(n);
    }
    return is;
  }

  // Jump-off point.
  public static boolean isSumOf(int[] set, int total, LinkedList<Integer> sum) {
    // Empty the list.
    sum.clear();
    // Start at 0 in the array.
    return isSumOf(set, total, 0, sum, 0);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> sum = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    int[] a = {18, 10, 6};
    int x = 18 + 10 + 6;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)+" ("+x+") = "+(isSumOf(a, x, sum)?Arrays.toString(sum.toArray()):"-"));
    x += 1;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)+" ("+x+") = "+(isSumOf(a, x, sum)?Arrays.toString(sum.toArray()):"-"));
    int[] b = {3,2};
    x = 12;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b)+" ("+x+") = "+(isSumOf(b, x, sum)?Arrays.toString(sum.toArray()):"-"));
    x += 1;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b)+" ("+x+") = "+(isSumOf(b, x, sum)?Arrays.toString(sum.toArray()):"-"));
    int[] c = {2,3};
    x = 12;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c)+" ("+x+") = "+(isSumOf(c, x, sum)?Arrays.toString(sum.toArray()):"-"));
    x += 1;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c)+" ("+x+") = "+(isSumOf(c, x, sum)?Arrays.toString(sum.toArray()):"-"));
  }
}
```

Edited to print the route taken.

Prints:

```
[18, 10, 6] (34) = [18, 10, 6]
[18, 10, 6] (35) = -
[3, 2] (12) = [3, 3, 3, 3]
[3, 2] (13) = [3, 3, 3, 2, 2]
[2, 3] (12) = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 3] (13) = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

Comment: In that case @Martin please be sure to learn from my techniques and try not to copy my code. You will understand a great deal more by doing it yourself. In future, if you are posting questions involving homework it may be better for you to make that clear and ask that complete solutions are not posted. I hope I have not harmed your chances of getting a good grade for this piece. Please remember that your teachers also have access to SO.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a slightly different strategy

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] s = { 4, 5 };
    System.out.println(isSumOf(s, 13)); // true
    System.out.println();

    int[] s1 = { 4, 9, 3 };
    System.out.println(isSumOf(s1, 15)); // true
    System.out.println();

    int[] s2 = { 4, 9, 3 };
    System.out.println(isSumOf(s2, 5)); // false
    System.out.println();

    int[] s3 = { 3, 2 };
    System.out.println(isSumOf(s3, 12)); // true
    System.out.println();

    int[] s4 = { 8, 10 };
    System.out.println(isSumOf(s4, 14)); // false
    System.out.println();
}

public static boolean isSumOf(int[] s, int n)
{
    return isSumOf(s, n, 0, 0, "");
}

private static boolean isSumOf(int[] s, int n, int i, int sum, String builder)
{
    if (sum == n) // if we found a subset
    {
        System.out.println(builder);
        return true;
    }

    if (i == s.length || sum > n) // 1. boundaries checks 2. if subset is greater then n
        return false;

    boolean with = isSumOf(s, n, i, sum + s[i], builder + s[i] + " "); // try to sum "s[i]", note that we can sum the
                                                                        // same "s[i]" multiple times

    boolean without = isSumOf(s, n, i + 1, sum, builder); // try to skip "s[i]" and instead to sum "s[i+1]"

    return with || without;
}
```